How to add text to the end of each line in Microsoft Word ONLY IF that line contains a specific character
How can a specific character be added to the end of each line in Microsoft Word if that line contains only a specific character? For some reason, they appear in the wrong place at times.
Before trying

Expected result

Tried but failed
I want all lines containing the letter a to have an asterisk added to the end of the related lines


Try the following macro:
Sub addAsterisk()

Dim currentParagraph As Paragraph

For Each currentParagraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  currentParagraph.Range.Select
  
  If Selection.Range.Find.Execute("a") Then
    Selection.MoveRight (wdCharacter)
    Selection.MoveLeft (wdCharacter)
    
    Selection.InsertAfter ("*")
  End If
  
Next

End Sub


This VBA works as the OP requires on Word 365
